# Как немедленно отправить конкретную порцию данных. Сокет C

Tags: linux, c, сокет

Есть сервер и есть клиент по передаче файлов, и там и там буфер для записи/чтения по 1450 байт.

Когда сервер отправляет последние данные файлы, клиент должен записать их в файл, а после, вывести сообщение о том, что загрузка прошла успешно (это сообщение тоже отправляет сервер, так же сервер отправляет еще одно сообщение - о доступных командах (меню)). В общем сервер работает через состояния. Я перечислил 3 из них:

1. отправка файла, пока файл не кончился (пока чтение из него по 1450 байт);
2. отправка сообщения об успешном завершении (когда последнее чтение было меньше 1450 байт, сервер меняет состояние клиента на 2);
3. отправка списка доступных команд (переход сюда, когда 2 было отправлено).

Проблема: сервер объединяет всё и отправляет разом (последние данные файла + сообщение об успехе + список доступных команд). Как мне сделать так, что бы сокет отправлял данные СРАЗУ, не накапливая сообщения в своем буфере?

**UPD:**

Условный код сервера (sc - client):

```
send(sc, "asd", 3, 0);
send(sc, "zxc", 3, 0);
```

Условный код клиента (ss - server):

```
recv(ss, buf, 1450, 0);
// что-то делаем + чистим буфер
recv(ss, buf, 1450, 0);
// что-то делаем
```

Первый вызов recv примет сразу "asdzxc", как их наверняка разделить? Что бы на первый recv пришел только asd, а на второй zxc. Может есть какие-то флаги для сокетов и их функций на подобные случаи? Пытался найти ответ в манах socket, send и recv, но ничего подобного там не увидел :(

**UPD2:**

Тип сокета - SOCK_STREAM

**UPD3:**

Вопрос решен в комментариях.

Comment: нужно увидеть код сервера и клиента. а так пустой разговор.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, обновил вопрос

Comment: Само слово STREAM намекает, что это непрерывный поток данных. Если вы хотите разделять данные в этом потоке — вам нужно самостоятельно придумать какой-нибудь разделитель

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо! Вот как я мог просто взять и догадаться об этом? Ни где об этом явно не написано... Где можно четко почитать о SOCK_STREAM? Не получается найти. Именно то, что происходит с передачей/приемом при объявлении сокета этим типом. Да, известно что надежный канал и прочее, но нужно по подробнее :)

Comment: @nx4n, очевидно, что писать программы  надо после чтения оригинальной документации -- [man 7 tcp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html)  (в первом же абзаце написано -- *`"TCP does not preserve record boundaries."`*)

Comment: @avp, спасибо, не догадался конкретно про TCP почитать в манах. Искал только маны функций, буду знать.

Comment: @nx4n, до кучи, в конце каждой manpage есть раздел SEE ALSO (в частности, в man socket, есть ссылка в т.ч. и на man 7 tcp)

Answer (score 1):

Для разделения данных на пакеты обычно используются протоколы высокого уровня.

Самый распространенный это структуры TLV. Сервер отправляет тип данных (например один байт), длинну передачи, а затем сами данные.

код клиента будет выглядеть примерно так.

```
while (1) {
  recv(ss, &t, 1, 0);
  if (t != 'd') break или continue или process = process_data;
  recv(ss, &l, 2, 0);
  recv(ss, buf, l, 0);
  process(buf, l);
}
```